# How to display SQL result separately

Tags: php, mysql, function, select, methods

I'm currently making a webpage which is meant to show all it's content from the database. So I made an SQL command which selects the data needed for only 1 particular field on the webpage.

Is it possible to make the SQL command so that it get's all the content for the page at once and that ill still be able to display it separately?
If so, how? Thanks

```
function dbGet() {
    global $conn;
    global $return;

    $sql = SELECT * FROM testTable;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $return = $row["text"];
            return $return;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    // $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: You want to return complete data of the table. Is it?

Comment: First problem, you're only returning 1 value, try: `$return[] = $row["text"];`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman If that's the best way to be able to display all the data serarately on the page, yes.

Comment: @AbraCadaver would that give me an array of everything im trying to select? And how do I display the selected data separately from each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in this way through which you can identify records has been there or not.

```
function dbGet() {
    global $conn;
    // I am not sure what is the datatype of $return here.
    // if it's having a predefined format,
    // please push the records into $return instead of creating as an array,
    // which will be taken care by framework if any you are using.

    // global $return;
    $return = array('status' => false, records => []);

    $sql = "SELECT text FROM testTable";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $return['status'] = true;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $return['records'][] = $row["text"];
        }
    }

    // $conn->close();
    return json_encode($return);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did some minor changes but the idea overall worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the results inside while loop instead of returning in whatever format you wish

If you are using php, you can try something like

```
echo $row["text"];
```

Hope it helps

Let me know if you require any further help

Answer (score 0):

First you should fix your return code as `@AbraCadaver` mentioned :

```
        $return[] = $row["text"];
```

Then you can use `foreach` in your  html :

```
<?php 
foreach($return as $r){

    echo $r['text'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Hmm ok, Can you explain how to display the selected data separately if I've applied this to my code??
e.g. In testTable are multiple records which need to be displayed apart from each other.

Comment: @Yorick what do you mean?  they are seperated!  `$return[0]['text']`  or  ``$return[1]['text']`` and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I think a **Json encoding** : `json_encode` will work well.

Try this: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php